# Vuecli config for development and production

Tags: webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I want to use different webpack configuration in vuecli vue.config.js for both production and development

Currently in my project i have a `vue.config.js` that has

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            ...splint chunks configuration
        }
    }
  }

}
```

The above runs splint chunk configuration in both development and production. How can i separate different webpack configuration for development and different configuration for production.

I have also tried adding

```
devServer: {
    configureWebpack: {
        optimization: {
            splitChunks: false
        }
    }
},
```

but still this doesnt work

In my package.json i have

```
{
"serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
"build": "vue-cli-service build"
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can use env variable. Build is production and serve is development.

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? false : true //or just process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    }
  }

}
```